# Trying to write dry code in Terraform, using Amazon S3 as backend but local terraform state is preventing success

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I have really simplified everything down to the basics to demonstrate the following: Create Two VPC structures, one for test & one for development, then trying to use exactly the same code (from the same folder) to place a security group into each environment, (test-vpc and dev-vpc).

Each VPC deployment is using a unique Amazon S3  backend, by using a unique key within the AWS S3 bucket to store the remote state file.

The security_group.tf, is utilizing a variable to point at the different S3 key file for terraform remote state files (key=var.vpc_choice). Where vpc_choice will equal the key value for S3 backend.

Then executing the terraform apply command twice from the same folder "terraform apply -vars-file=test.tfvars" and then once again with a different variable "terraform apply -vars-file=dev.tfvars".

My expectation is that the security group is provisioned into a different VPC because the variable is point to the different backend state.

However, the local terraform state in that folder is getting in my way. It doesn't matter that I'm pointing at a remote state, the local state file knows the security group was already provisioned and wants to destroy that security group and create the security group in the other VPC.

IT works if I copy the code to another folder like "groups2". The first Terraform apply, provisions to test-vpc and the second terraform apply (as long as the code is in a different folder), provisions into dev-vpc. So while the code is exactly the same, and does provision into two different VPC's because of the variable answered with a .tfvars file, I have not achieved the ability to provision from the same folder.

The BIG question is, is that possible, have I missed something like an ability to not care about the local state file so I can provision to different VPCs by using a variable?

You will find a copy of my code at https://github.com/surfingjoe/Proposed_Terraform_Modules

Comment: You should really look into using terraform workspaces to manage this. When you switch workspaces on the command line it will switch your local state to match the selected workspace. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/workspaces.html

Comment: Thank you, using a Terraform workspace did the trick.  If you don't mind, as I'm just teaching myself Terraform, I don't know the normal practice.  Question: Would this be the normal practice, to use the same folder and then use Terraform Workspace?

Comment: Yes this is the entire purpose of Terraform Workspaces, to allow you to deploy multiple environments like "dev" and "test" without duplicating code.

Answer (score 0):

Mark B commented on my question, but in fact, answered the question.  Thank you Mark!

Using Terraform Workspaces works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

One environment = one remote backend (*one tfstate file*)

So, If you have two environments you have to open each folder, set unique name for `tfstate` in the remote backend, and run `terraform apply`.

Comment: If you want to deploy two (_or more_) environments from the one place, look at on the `Terragrunt`